# Can't mount large external large disk(3TB) on ubuntu server 12.10

Tags: server, mount, disk

When I connect with e-sata or usb for external disk, the display shows the following message:

```
[534.032718] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 ASct 0x0 Serr 0x5840000 action 0xe frozen [534.033063] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040,connection status changed [534.033403] ata3: SError: { CommWake LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch }

[24.360696] ata3: exception Emask 0x10 ASct 0x0 Serr 0x5950000 action 0xe frozen [24.360708] ata3: irq_stat 0x00000040,connection status changed [24.360717] ata3: Serr: {PHYRdyChg CommWake Dispar LinkSeq TrStaTrns DevExch } [30.084024] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
```

**fdisk can found the external disk,and I use parted seted. But using mount disk ,shows the following message:

```
message,can't mount disk**

[873.367903] EXT3-fs error (device sdb1): ext3_check_descriptors:Block bitmap for group 320 not in group (block 540385280)! [873.369151] EXT3-fs (sdb1): error group descriptors corrupted mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg|tail or so
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you have a problem with the 4K blocks of the 3TB drive. It should be possible. I've a storage with a lot of 3TB drives running the old debian squeeze but with a 3.4.8 kernel and I'll upgrade soon to a ubuntu 12.04 lts.

I've took a look at the ext3 src and found your error message in ( http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext3/super.c ):

```
/* Called at mount-time, super-block is locked */
static int ext3_check_descriptors(struct super_block *sb)
```

So your ubuntu can't read 4K devices. Take a look here: http://lwn.net/Articles/377895/

Comment: the same hardware install MS or FreeNAS.it can connect external disk.other talk may about "parted".that say don't use parted of ubuntu, compile parted source of GNU.